# Bouncing Ease Equation in C#

Tags: c#, easing, bounce, easing-functions

I'm trying to add a bounce effect to an element of a game I'm making using C#. I can't seem to find the correct easing equation for this. Here's what I'm using for the time being:

```
t.position += (destination-t.position)*0.05f;
    if((destination-t.position).magnitude <= 0.01f)
    {
        t.position = destination;
    }
```

Can anyone help me with changing it to a bouncing equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(setUpEase)
    {
        // Set the destination of each boardspace
        if(!oneTime)
        {
            beginning = new Vector3(t.position.x, t.position.y, t.position.z);
            destination = new Vector3(t.position.x, t.position.y-10, t.position.z);
            change = new Vector3(0, -10, 0);
            setUpDuration = Random.Range (1.0f, 3.0f);
            oneTime = true;
        }

        // BOUNCING
        currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
        float t2 = currentTime/setUpDuration;
        if(currentTime < setUpDuration)
        {
            if (t2 < (1/2.75f))
            {
                t.position = change*(7.5625f*t2*t2) + beginning;
            }
            else if (t2 < (2/2.75f))
            {
                t.position = change*(7.5625f*(t2-=(1.5f/2.75f))*t2 + 0.75f) + beginning;
            }
            else if (t2 < (2.5f/2.75f))
            {
                t.position = change*(7.5625f*(t2-=(2.25f/2.75f))*t2 + 0.9375f) + beginning;
            }
            else
            {
                t.position = change*(7.5625f*(t2-=(2.625f/2.75f))*t2 + 0.984375f) + beginning;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            t.position = destination;
            if(boardId < 113 && boardId > 92)
                pie.setUpEase2 = true;
            setUpEase=false;
        }
    }
```